# comparing dict returned by json.dumps using mock in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-requests

My python tool, "Bar", has to obtain key from certain server. It uses `requests.post` method. I want to write unit test, which will check if `post` is called with correct arguments. Here is how test looks like:

```
@mock.patch('bar_project.bar.main.requests.post')
def test_correct_request_call(self,
                              mock_requests_post):

    client = Bar.Bar(t_url, t_user_name, t_user_password)

    expected_call_args = ({'data': '{"password": "t_user_password", "username": "t_user_name"}',
                           'headers': {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
                           'url': 't_url/apilogin',
                           'verify': False})

    mock_requests_post_call_kwargs = mock_requests_post.call_args[1]
    self.assertEqual(mock_requests_post_call_kwargs, expected_call_args)
```

The thing is that there is 50% of chances that test would pass. It is not deterministic. As sometimes `mock_requests_post.call_args[1]` returns dict with `data` value:

`'{"username": "t_user_name", "password": "t_user_password"}'`
and sometimes with
`'{"password": "t_user_password", "username": "t_user_name"}'`.

How can I rewrite test to keep it simple but still check arguments i called `post` with?

Comment: If you're using `requests`, the easiest way to test it that I've found is using [`responses`](https://github.com/getsentry/responses). Alternatively just `json.loads` the string and compare it as an actual dictionary.

Comment: Yea, i divided one assert into four different in this one test. Why don't you post this an an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe suggested, I used `json.loads` to create new `dict` by loading string returned by `requests.post` and then compare it alongside other arguments comparisons. Now test passes each time.

```
@mock.patch('slot_project.Slot.main.requests.post')
def test_correct_request_call(self,
                              mock_requests_post):

    slot_client = Slot.Slot(t_url, t_user_name, t_user_password)

    mock_requests_post_call_kwargs = mock_requests_post.call_args[1]

    self.assertEqual(json.loads(mock_requests_post_call_kwargs['data']),
                     {"username": "t_user_name", "password": "t_user_password"})
    self.assertEqual(mock_requests_post_call_kwargs['headers'], {'Content-type': 'application/json'})
    self.assertEqual(mock_requests_post_call_kwargs['url'], 't_url/apilogin')
    self.assertFalse(mock_requests_post_call_kwargs['verify'])
```